# Load modules in Perl at run time and share it between threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

Is it possible to load modules at run time, `require '/file_path/file_name.pm';` , and share the memory between threads?

Basically, I have a pool of threads, if thread#1 decides to load a module, I want the module available to all the threads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No, it's not possible.
Either the module must be loaded before the thread is created, or each
thread must individually load the module."

Thanks to Dave Mitchell [1](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.ithreads/2011/07/msg1367.html)